# How to set Data Source In Crystal Report from View Model in MVVM pattern WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, crystal-reports

Below is my Code for setting the Document in the View Model

```
    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
            report.Load("Reports/Test.rpt");
            var data_ = db.Det_QualificationMaster.Where(x => x.MUA_id == 6)
                .Select(x => new { x.CollageName, x.StartYear, x.EndYear 
                           }).ToList();

            report.SetDataSource(data_);
```

Code in the Page

```
  <viewer:CrystalReportsViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="crystalReportsViewer1"  
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="400" Width="400" >
```

How can I Bind the Data from view model to the page

Comment: Which version of Crystal Reports does this apply to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the Solution Myself Thought I share  With you all.Big Thank to Andre-Alves Lima Blog here's the Link http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2016/07/20/utilizando-o-crystal-reports-com-mvvm-no-wpf/

it's in Portuguese so Translate I'm putting the code Below

Add a static Class **ReportSourceBehaviour.cs**

```
public static class ReportSourceBehaviour
    {
        public static readonly System.Windows.DependencyProperty ReportSourceProperty =
            System.Windows.DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "ReportSource",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(ReportSourceBehaviour),
                new System.Windows.PropertyMetadata(ReportSourceChanged));

        private static void ReportSourceChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var crviewer = d as SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.CrystalReportsViewer;
            if (crviewer != null)
            {
                crviewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = e.NewValue;
            }
        }

        public static void SetReportSource(System.Windows.DependencyObject target, object value)
        {
            target.SetValue(ReportSourceProperty, value);
        }

        public static object GetReportSource(System.Windows.DependencyObject target)
        {
            return target.GetValue(ReportSourceProperty);
        }
    }
```

in ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument Report { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Report = new NameOfRptFile();
        //Add data to the report
    }
}
```

in Page (XAML)

```
<Window xmlns:Viewer="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer"  x:Class="CrystalWPFMVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CrystalWPFMVVM"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <Viewer:CrystalReportsViewer x:Name="CrystalReportsViewer"
                                     local:ReportSourceBehaviour.ReportSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Report, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=FrameworkElement}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```